# Subject of 'asking' in: 'sent a letter asking'

Tags: parts-of-speech, subjects, clauses

In the sentence ...

> The client sent me a letter asking if we could change the information for them.

... what is the semantic/syntactic subject of the verb *asking*? Are there any tests we can do to verify the syntactic subject?

Comment: You can easily see the potential candidates for "deleted subject" by trying to reinstate one: *The client sent me a letter asking **me/us** if we could change the information for them.* It's only a bit awkward deciding whether it should be ***me*** or ***us*** because the original here explicitly includes both *sent **me*** and *asking if **we***. But obviously the writer receives requests *on behalf of a group* (and may or may not be the individual who actually *carries out* the requested action), so semantically they net down to the same thing anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So [what/who]'s doing the *asking*? Is it the client or the letter? That's what I'm unsure about ... It seems you're trying to reinstate an *Object* of *ask*, no? - but that's not part of the question here ...

Comment: I suppose pragmatically the *client* is doing the asking (through a letter), but grammatically the *letter* appears to be the subject. But the same "ambiguity" exists in, say, *"He gave me a map showing the way"*, which you *could* deconstruct as *"[While] showing the way he gave me a map"*. But usually we wouldn't see it that way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, exactly. Though not sure how to tell if the letter *is* the subject. So I'm wondering if there's some kind of test we could do to figure out what we're really processing as the subject there ... ? (shrugs - but in hope)

Comment: Per my previous example, unless you're willing to parse yours as *"The client [in the process of] asking if we could change the information for them sent me a letter"*, you probably have to accept that it's the *letter* doing the (vicarious, on behalf of the client) asking.

Answer (score 2):

It's the letter which is the subject of *asking*.

The client sent the letter. The client did not ask the letter's recipient: he didn't speak to him at all. The client merely sent the letter.

The client sent ... what? The letter asking something. The letter which asked something.

However you parse the sentence, the grammatical syntactic subject of *asking* is the *letter*.

Semantically it may well be different, because only people ask; letters don't. The client asked something by means of a letter. But that's not how the original sentence is arranged.

Comment: Do you have any grammatical tests/evidence to back that up? I'm not saying that I disagree btw, it's just that the evidence you've given is entirely semantic, it seems ...

Comment: The client sent the letter, the letter asking something. That's not semantic.

Comment: How come? That's not syntactic. For example if we analyse a sentence: There came 1,000 troops running down the hill, the kind of argument you've given could be given to try and show that *1,000 troops* is the subject of *came*. However, the subject of *came* in that sentence is *there*, not *1,000* troops.

Comment: I think that has probably justified my analysis. The subject of *came* is certainly *there* (just as "The client sent..."). The subject of *running,* if it can be analysed as requiring a subject, must be *troops,* not the dummy *there*. But comments are not for discussion.

Comment: We can delete them as we go though, not to leave everything too messy. Actually, the standard analysis of that sentence is that both *troops* and *running* are separate complements of *came*. Part of the evidence is that we could also say: *There came running down the hill 1,00 troops* instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one logical transformation of the sentence:

The client sent me  letter in which he asked if ...

Normally only persons ask questions, letters are no persons
and ask no qestions.

Comment: Are you saying that *client* is the grammatical subject of *asking*? If so, could you give us any evidence at all?

Comment: You have to insert "he" in the transformed sentence and "he" is the client. I think you have to decide this by logic. The evidence is that a letter doesn't speak and ask questions.

Comment: but it does in this sentence. the letter is clearly doing the asking here. it doesn't have to make sense in the real world, it's just grammar.